# XSLT skipping name spaces

Tags: xslt-2.0

I've an XML document like below.

```
<user:doc>
    <user:md>
        <user:md.number>user 1</user:md.number>
        <user:md.name>David</user:md.name>
        <user:md.address>AL</user:md.address>
    </user:md>
</user:doc>
```

I need to write an XSLT to retrieve this user name. I know a way like below.

```
<xsl:template match="user:doc">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "user:md">
<xsl:value-of select = "./user:md.name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But I want to know if I can skip the namespace and directly match like `xsl:template match="doc">....</xsl:template>`

Also using `<xsl:template match="user:doc">` gives me the below error.

```
File C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\XML\XSLT\chapters.xsl is not valid.
    Undefined namespace prefix 'user'
        Error location: xsl:stylesheet / xsl:template / @match
        Details
            XPST0081: A namespace prefix used in an expression must be expandable into a namespace URI using the statically known namespaces
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="*:doc">
```

Comment: And then, should I/ Can I directly take `<xsl:template match ="md">`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define

```
xpath-default-namespace="http://foo.bar.com/ns"
```

as an attribute of `xsl:stylesheet`. If you do this, then `match="md"` is interpreted as matching elements with local name `md` and namespace URI `http://foo.bar.com/ns`.

Comment: Hi Sir, How can i get the value of  `user.md.name`?

Comment: Your example has user:md.name, not user.md.name. If you use xpath-default-namespace, all element names in that namespace can be unprefixed, so you just write `select="md.name"`.